# How can I provide configuration variables to a Sass/SCSS file before including it?

Tags: sass

I'm migrating a Stylus library to SCSS since [Angular 12 has deprecated Stylus](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/releases/tag/v12.0.0) and I'm in that impacted 0.3%. I've run into something we were doing that I'm not sure how to convert to SCSS—maybe it's impossible.

Let me lay this out simply: I work on several projects that all use loads of the same styles, so we put those styles together into one style sheet in its own NPM package. We can then just grab `@import '@company/design/styles';` and suddenly we've got all of our regular styles and variables and mixins available in the project, or we can import `@import '@company/package/styles/common';` for just the variables and mixins.

The thing is, our projects might need to configure the library before we import it. Suppose the library contains this bit:

```scss
// @company/package/styles/_forms.scss
input:invalid {
  background: url('/assets/input-error.svg') no-repeat center right;
}
```

Not every project will have `/assets/input-error.svg` at that exact location. Maybe one of my projects has to use `/subfolder/static/input-error.svg`.

I could include this then overwrite `input:invalid { background-image: url(...) }` to supply it with the correct location, but there may be *many* references to this particular file and many other assets on top of that to correct. So we instead, in our Stylus library, we introduced an `$asset-input-error` variable that points to `/assets/input-error.svg` by default and did something like this:

```scss
// @company/package/styles/_forms.scss
input:invalid {
  background: url($asset-input-error) no-repeat center right;
}
```

```scss
// the local project
$asset-input-error: '/subfolder/static/input-error.svg';
@import '@company/package/styles';
```

The above is heavily simplified and isn't actually legitimate SCSS, but I hope it conveys what we're trying to do: we want to set up what are effectively environment variables in our SCSS, include the common style sheet, and have it use those variables.

The thing is, I'm not sure what the legitimate or idiomatic approach is to do this in SCSS. Unlike Stylus, which has a global scope for its variables, SCSS would have me `@use '../config';` and reference `config.$asset-input-error`, and from outside the library there's no way I see to change the configuration to point that asset to a different location. I'm sure SCSS *has* a way for me to do this, but I'm not sure what it is. Do I convert the entire library into a giant mixin to which I pass optional configuration? Do I do something with global variables? Something else?

**How can I provide variables to my SCSS style sheet to configure it as part of including it in a project?**

Ultimately the end goal here is just to be able to say to the library things like: “the assets to reference are here” (very important) or “the error color is *this* in this particuilar project” (less important).

Answer (score 2):

### Using `@import`

You can use global variables declared before the `@import` as you stated.

[SCSS Documentation for this method](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/at-rules/import#configuring-modules-through-imports)

**`@company/package/styles/_forms.scss`**

```css
$asset-input-error: '/subfolder/static/input-error.svg' !default;

input:invalid {
  background: url($asset-input-error) no-repeat center right;
}
```

**`@company/package/styles/styles.scss`**

```css
@import 'forms';
```

**`local.scss`**

```css
$asset-input-error: '/different/path/input-error.svg';
@import '@company/package/styles';
```

[CodeSandbox Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/scss-configure-imported-modules-nbtfi)

### Using `@use [...] with`

You can also hop aboard the `@use` train if you prefer to future-proof your library.

[SCSS Documentation for this method](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/at-rules/use#configuration)

[SCSS Documentation for using mixins](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/at-rules/use#with-mixins)

[SCSS Documentation for configuring forwards](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/at-rules/forward#configuring-modules)

**`@company/package/styles/_forms.scss`**

```css
$asset-input-error: '/subfolder/static/input-error.svg' !default;

input:invalid {
  background: url($asset-input-error) no-repeat center right;
}
```

**`@company/package/styles/styles.scss`**

```css
@forward 'forms';
```

**`local.scss`**

```css
@use 'styles' with (
  $asset-input-error: '/different/path/input-error.svg'
);
```

Sadly CodeSandbox and StackBlitz don't support dart-sass, so I don't have a live demo for this but I tested it on the latest version of sass from npm.